# Itertools function to generate unique permutations

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I want to know if there is an `itertools` way to produce the following combinations/permutations:

```
list = ['x', 'o']

# when character 'x' is allowed to occupy 1 place with total places of 4:

a = [['o','o','o','x'],
     ['o','o','x','o'],
     ['o','x','o','o'],
     ['x','o','o','o']]

# when character 'x' is allowed to occupy 2 places with total places of 4:

b = [['o','o','x','x'],
     ['o','x','x','o'],
     ['x','x','o','o'],
     ['x','o','x','o'],
     ['o','x','o','x'],
     ['x','o','o','x']]
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this using `itertools.product` or a similar function to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) also accepts strings as paramater:

```
from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations("ooox"))
[('o', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'o')]
```

and

```
>>> list(permutations("ooxx"))
[('o', 'o', 'x', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'x'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'x', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'x', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'x'), ('o', 'o', 'x', 'x'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'x', 'x', 'o'), ('o', 'x', 'o', 'x'), ('o', 'x', 'x', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('x', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('x', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('x', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('x', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('x', 'o', 'o', 'x'), ('x', 'o', 'x', 'o'), ('x', 'x', 'o', 'o'), ('x', 'x', 'o', 'o')]
```

To store them in a list of lists as shown in your question you can use `map(list, permutations("ooox"))`.

As you mentioned in the comment section, we can write a specific function for that job, that takes the inputs you want, but notice this will behave in a not so desired way when the first string is not of length 1:

```
from itertools import permutations
def iterate(lst, length, places):
    return set(permutations(lst[0]*(length-places)+lst[1]*places))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(iterate(["o","x"], 4, 1))
{('o', 'o', 'o', 'x'),
 ('o', 'o', 'x', 'o'),
 ('o', 'x', 'o', 'o'),
 ('x', 'o', 'o', 'o')}
>>> pprint(iterate(["o","x"], 4, 2))
{('o', 'o', 'x', 'x'),
 ('o', 'x', 'o', 'x'),
 ('o', 'x', 'x', 'o'),
 ('x', 'o', 'o', 'x'),
 ('x', 'o', 'x', 'o'),
 ('x', 'x', 'o', 'o')}
```

Comment: Your answer seems to have many duplicates in them. We could take uniques, but I'm looking for a function where I can specify the number of places (4 in the example) and the number of places an element X can occupy (in the example I give two cases , 1 and 2)

Comment: I don't think `itertools` have a special function for this *exact* problem. However, it's not hard to write a function that takes a list of length 2, the size and space desired and uses the line I've shown to output your list. But I guess it would be very specific.

Comment: @user3063482 Note that using `set` is likely to be very inefficient if the number of elements and number of `'x'` gets bigger. Also you'll lose the memory efficiency of a generator. But as pointed out a "carefully tailored" solution would be really specific. There's some tradeoff there. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own function (or generator) based on [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

def equivalence_permutations(x, o):
    """Create all unique permutations with `x` x'es and `o` o's."""
    total = x+o
    for indices in combinations(range(total), x):
        lst = ['o']*total
        for index in indices:
            lst[index] = 'x'
        yield lst
```

The `combinations` makes sure the indices are unique without needing to use `set` or any other greedy operation. So it should be much faster in those cases. For example:

```
>>> list(equivalence_permutations(2, 2))  # 2 x and 2 o
[['x', 'x', 'o', 'o'],
 ['x', 'o', 'x', 'o'],
 ['x', 'o', 'o', 'x'],
 ['o', 'x', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', 'o', 'x'],
 ['o', 'o', 'x', 'x']]

>>> list(equivalence_permutations(1, 3))  # 1 x and 3 o
[['x', 'o', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'x', 'o', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', 'x', 'o'],
 ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x']]
```